# Comparing two rows in mysql with additional check

Tags: mysql

Heysa,

I have this little problem that im not quite good at mysql queries and i don't know proper terminology for this question so i'll just roll as i can :)

I have 2 rows in 1 table that i want to compare if they are not 0 and are equal.
In php it would look something like this:

```
if(!empty($row1) && !empty($row2)){
   if($row1==$row2){
       return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Here is table if that's any help

```
id | b | t |
-----------
1 | 2 | 1 |
2 | 0 | 0 | 
3 | 1 | 1 |
```

And this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE b=t
```

Returns also 0=0 record with id=2 ( that i don't want )

Correct query should return only record with id=3

Comment: What is your table structure? What columns are you using to link the rows? What has to be not 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE b = t AND b <> 0 AND t <> 0`

Since we're testing that `b = t`, we know that if `b <> 0` is true, then `t <> 0` is also true. We can therefore shorten it to

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE b = t AND b <> 0`